# How to call displayInputDialog when a row is clicked?

Tags: android

*I want the user to click on the row in the listView and so that my dialog is called.I have a dialog xml file .I don't want the user to click on a button I want to click on a row.

```
                                                                          * 
public class Edit_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DatabaseClass  database;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
    Dialog d;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        database = new DatabaseClass(getApplicationContext());

        sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor=database.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String id, product_name, category;
                id = cursor.getString(0);
                product_name = cursor.getString(1);
                category = cursor.getString(2);
                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(id, product_name, category);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext()


                    );

        }

    }



     @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_id);
                sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

*Input dialog:This my input dialog ,when the user clicks on a row this has to come up.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_margin="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingLeft="15dp"
       android:paddingRight="15dp"
       android:paddingTop="10dp"
       >

       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:singleLine="true"
               android:hint="Name"
               />


       </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/updateBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UPDATE"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#009968"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


</LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this link will usefull to you. https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: Thats a button example I'm not using a button I'm just clicking on a specific row

Comment: which dialog? try to provide full details when asking questions

Comment: @Anders I have a dialog xml file ,I have edited my post and put in the dialog file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest example to display the dialog, you can further modify it as your needs

```
private void showDialog(){
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.YourDialogLayout);
        dialog.setTitle("Here Goes the Title");
        dialog.show();
    }
```

call `showDialog();` in your `onItemClick`.